# Not able to use the model.fit() in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

Please help me run the code. This doesn't work. I have been trying hard to solve this for days. The model_final.fit() also doesn't work. Why is this showing the same error for the method. This is almost the entire code.

EDIT: The train_generator and validation_generator added.

```
img_width, img_height = 400, 400
train_data_dir = "data/train"
validation_data_dir = "data/validation"
nb_train_samples = 4125
nb_validation_samples = 466
batch_size = 16,
epochs = 5

output_num_classes = 2

K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
model = applications.VGG19(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

model.summary()

x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(output_num_classes, activation="softmax")(x)

model_final = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)
model_final.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
                    optimizer=optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   zoom_range=0.3,
                                   width_shift_range=0.3,
                                   height_shift_range=0.3,
                                   rotation_range=30,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                                    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   zoom_range=0.3,
                                   width_shift_range=0.3,
                                   height_shift_range=0.3,
                                   rotation_range=30,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,
                                                              target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                                              batch_size = batch_size,
                                                              class_mode='categorical')
```

The code above is before fitting.

````
model_final.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                          steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
                          epochs = epochs,
                          validation_data = validation_generator,
                          validation_steps = nb_validation_samples)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1844: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  warnings.warn('`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and '
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-b195f52ce8fb> in <module>()
      3                           epochs = epochs,
      4                           validation_data = validation_generator,
----> 5                           validation_steps = nb_validation_samples)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __len__(self)
     66 
     67     def __len__(self):
---> 68         return (self.n + self.batch_size - 1) // self.batch_size  # round up
     69 
     70     def on_epoch_end(self):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple' ```
````

Comment: Add the rest of your code (train_generator, validation_generator). Also, as stated in the output, you should not use `fit_generator()` anymore, since it is deprecated. `fit()` now supports generators so use it instead.

Comment: That part is fine. I guess. In future version it will be deprecated. The other problem set the function is working. I will edit the code.

Comment: What is the value of batch_size? Please post the code that computes that value

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I uploaded the entire code now. Could you please help me out solving the issue. I have been stuck now for quite a time. Could you please assist?

Comment: There is a comma in your batch size definition ( batch_size = 16, ), the comma should not be there as it transforms the integer into a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue with sample code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

train_dir  = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/train'
test_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/test'

img_width, img_height = 224, 224
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

epochs = 8
batch_size = 32,

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255,
    horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255)

train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')

test_data = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    class_mode = 'binary')


Conv_Base = ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = input_shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv_Base)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer = 'Adam',
            metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

model.fit(
        train_data,
        steps_per_epoch = 10,
        epochs = 2,
        validation_data = test_data,
        verbose = 1,
        validation_steps = 32)
```

Output:

```
Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1018 images belonging to 2 classes.
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Functional)        (None, 7, 7, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 100352)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               25690368  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 49,278,337
Trainable params: 49,225,217
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5a5644117355> in <module>()
     60         validation_data = test_data,
     61         verbose = 1,
---> 62         validation_steps = 32)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __len__(self)
     66 
     67     def __len__(self):
---> 68         return (self.n + self.batch_size - 1) // self.batch_size  # round up
     69 
     70     def on_epoch_end(self):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

**Solution to fix:**

As rightly suggested by @Dr. Snoopy, this issue was due to `comma` right after `batch_size` definition. It converts the `integer` into a `tuple` and which is not supported.

Changing `batch_size = 32,` to `batch_size = 32` has resolved the issue.

Working code as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

train_dir  = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/train'
test_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dogs_Vs_Cats/test'

img_width, img_height = 224, 224
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

epochs = 8
batch_size = 32    # removed comma


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255,
    horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1. /255)

train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')

test_data = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    class_mode = 'binary')


Conv_Base = ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = input_shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv_Base)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer = 'Adam',
            metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

model.fit(
        train_data,
        steps_per_epoch = 10,
        epochs = 2,
        validation_data = test_data,
        verbose = 1,
        validation_steps = 32)
```

Output:

```
Drive already mounted at /content/drive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True).
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1018 images belonging to 2 classes.
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Functional)        (None, 7, 7, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 100352)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               25690368  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 49,278,337
Trainable params: 49,225,217
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
10/10 [==============================] - 107s 10s/step - loss: 9.5302 - precision_1: 0.6096 - recall_1: 0.6485 - val_loss: 14405.0479 - val_precision_1: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall_1: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - 68s 7s/step - loss: 2.2295 - precision_1: 0.8191 - recall_1: 0.8799 - val_loss: 3977.1418 - val_precision_1: 0.4912 - val_recall_1: 1.0000
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fbba005cc50>
```